# Navigation bar item automatically changes its height and position in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode9.2, xcode9.1

I have a project which was build in `Xcode 8.2` and now when I run it using `Xcode 9.2`. I am facing problems with the `custom navigation title` and `bar buttons` in the `view controllers`. In my `storyboard` I have a `View Controller` and on its `Navigation bar` I have a custom `navigation view` with a `label` used as the `navigation title`.

Since we cannot add `constraints` on the `navigation view`, I have given `autolayout` for both the `view` and `label`.  Now when I run the project, the `custom navigation title` has disappeared. So I opened the `storyboard` to check what really happened, I was shocked to see that `navigation view's origin.y` value is changed to some other value, like `-44, -88,` etc. Now I edited the `origin.y value`, saved and run the project, but still the view was not seen. So now when I checked back in the `storyboard` the frame of the view was changed to some other value. I tried creating new custom navigation view, but no luck. This keeps happening and  I am really worried. I really appreciate if you guys can give me some information on this issue.

[Click to show screenshot of custom view in the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBL8e.png)

Comment: Please add some code or screenshots.

Comment: try changing the hugging and compression priority. Maybe that will help

Comment: How did you added custom navigation title and bar buttons?

Comment: @aBilal17 :- I not changing the frame in code.This is in the storyboard.Will try to get the screenshot.

Comment: @MoazKhan:- I haven't  put any constraint on the view

Comment: @SaadChaudhry :- Simply drag the view from interface builder to the view controller in the storyboard and put a ui label in the added view.This is how i  created the custom navigation title.

Comment: @aBilal17 :- I have added screen shot

Comment: why is navigation item here? Aren't you using custom navigation bar?